# Elasticsearch: Searching on boolean field

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a couple of documents in an Elasticsearch Cluster having a field `isInFight` holding a boolean value. Mapping is set correctly (already double-checked this) to boolean.

When I run a search with:

```
 curl -XGET localhost:9200/default/_search --data '{"query": {"term": {"isInFight": true}}}'
```

I get documents returned with the field being true and false. Changing the value in my search query to `false` no documents are returned at all.

To me this looks like the term query checked for the field being present or not rather then for it's value. Everything I found on the internet suggests that this query is the way to go though.

Am I missing something here? Is there a known bug regarding this?

The Elasticsearch in question is version `5.5.2` with lucene version `6.6.0` on an ubuntu `16.04` server.

Comment: Works fine for me. Can you share what you get from `curl -XGET localhost:9200/default` ?

Comment: Stripped it down a bit as the mapping is rather big:
`{"default":{"mappings":{"logevent":{ ... "isInFight":{"type":"boolean"} ... }}, "settings":{...}}}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this in my local elasticsearch and didn't find the issue

```
POST test_index/doc
{
  "id": 1,
  "isInFight": false
}

POST test_index/doc
{
  "id": 2,
  "isInFight": true
}

POST test_index/doc
{
  "id": 3,
  "isInFight": true
}

GET test_index/doc/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": { "isInFight": false }
  }
}
```

and got this result

```
{
  "took": 4,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 0.2876821,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test_index",
        "_type": "doc",
        "_id": "AWU2Dxm7GR2l1TPuyKhN",
        "_score": 0.2876821,
        "_source": {
          "id": 1,
          "isInFight": false
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: In a clean environment I can confirm that this works. What I noticed is that the documents return the boolean value differently. In the clean environment it is `"isInFight": true` while in my 'bugged' environment it is `"isInFight": "True"`.

I tinkered around with this a bit and when I enter documents with `"True"` and `"False"` as value the error occurs again. Thus I suspect the issue being with inserting documents.

Comment: @Dero yeah, bad data can cause an issue.

Comment: @deerawan what happens if you add a document where isInFight=Null, or isInFlight is not present in the document ... what happens if you filter on False?

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "term": {
          "isInFight": true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This throws a parsing exception for me: `curl -XGET localhost:9200/default/_search --data '{ "filter": { "bool": { "must": { "term": { "isInFight": true } } } } }'`
`{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [filter].","line":1,"col":13}],"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [filter].","line":1,"col":13},"status":400}`